# how to disable a button for a specific time in php

Tags: php

I have an edit button for users to edit their posted jobs. I want that button to disable or disappear  a week after published day.how can I do this in php. thanks advance...

Comment: Well a beautiful `if` using the post date and the current date should do the trick ...
Is it really your question? Maybe you want to know how to compare date ?

Comment: Store the date in a database. Use a control structure to check the current time, if it is right, then print the html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $timePublished = 1334301250; // unix time when job posted
    $afterOneWeek  = $timePublished+(60*60*24*7); // 1 week
    $dateNow       = date('U'); // unix time for Date Now
    if($dateNow > $afterOneWeek){ // if Date Now is greater than our "After One Week"
        echo "<button>Button is now visible</button>";
    } else {
        echo "No button, one week not passed";
    }
?>
```